# How to get some letters after a specefic word in string in kotlin?

Tags: android, string, android-studio, kotlin

I have a string like this

```
"connect successfully , phonenumber:09100000000 ,email:alaki@yahoo.com"
```

then i want to grab a phonenumber from this string , i want a string "09100000000"
anybody has an idea ???

Comment: Kotlin or Java?

Comment: @Aniox i want it in kotlin language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer as answer of @arvind-kumar-avinash seems work and correct

but i use this simple code

```
val str = "connect successfully , phonenumber:09100000000 ,email:alaki@yahoo.com"
println(body.substringAfter("phonenumber:","not found").substringBefore(" ,email","not found"))
```

and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Java regex API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) as shown below:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "connect successfully , phonenumber:09100000000 ,email:alaki@yahoo.com";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=phonenumber:)\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        String phone = matcher.find() ? matcher.group() : "";
        System.out.println(phone);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
09100000000
```

**Explanation of the regex:**`(?<=phonenumber:)\\d+` specifies digits (i.e. `\\d+`) preceded by `phonenumber:`. The syntax, `?<=` is used to specify a [positive look-behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
val regex : Regex = Regex("(?<=phonenumber:)\\d+")
fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    regex.findAll("connect successfully , phonenumber:09100000000 ,email:alaki@yahoo.com")
            .forEach { println(it.groupValues) }
}
```

Underlying regex borrowed from the answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash.